# How can I import only one icon from fontawesome?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuetify.js

I'm searching keyboard-arrow-down icon for my Expansion Panel from vuetify

I have installed

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.5.0",
}
```

fontawesome-free, but I think it installed all icons and fonts

So Is there are way to import only one icon (keyboard-arrow-down)?

I've searched my node-modules, but I couldn't find it.

Here's my code.

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'fa'
 })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the dependencies:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core \
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons \
npm i --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
```

Import individual icons:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faCoffee)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

Use it:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <font-awesome-icon icon="coffee" />
  </div>
</template>
```

[Vue.js reference documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs)

**Update**

Bundle sizes for reference using Vue CLI 3:

```
1. Single Icon

File                                 Size               Gzipped

dist/js/chunk-vendors.0ce8e3e3.js    135.62 KiB         46.03 KiB
dist/js/app.d98fb35c.js              2.30 KiB           1.13 KiB

2. All Icons

File                                 Size               Gzipped

dist/js/chunk-vendors.7833710c.js    767.94 KiB         249.05 KiB
dist/js/app.b7f38b90.js              2.36 KiB           1.17 KiB
```

Comment: Can I use it with Vuetify?

Comment: You certainly can.

Comment: Is it safe to uninstall `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` then?