# Best Practice to include Font-Awesome at BEST Performance

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, font-face, webfonts

I used font-awesome in my project by include this CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Google Page Speed not seem to like it.
[image]

Not to mentioned, I only used 5 icons

```
view-source:https://www.bunlongheng.com/
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to import an entire library for just 5 icons. Download the SVGs and pull them in as icons or images

Comment: Any suggestions or link on how to do that ? images ? I'm afraid it's even more expensive than 6.5 kib;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from a quick search in the internet i am afraid that font awesome doesn't have any service like what you are looking for :( but there are some solutions !

if you are using a frame work like React , Vue or Angular you are able to import only the fonts you need

[How can I import only one icon from fontawesome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298778/how-can-i-import-only-one-icon-from-fontawesome)

like here ^

if you are using vanilla javascript you will have to use other website to help you with that like

https://icomoon.io/app

or

https://fontello.com/

> A font is a single file, much like an image or a document. It doesn't matter how you
> include it in your CSS -- users will still download the whole font
> file. The CSS definitions just make the font available on your web
> site.
>
> There are some things that you could do as an alternative. There are
> some companies that will allow you to generate partial font sets using
> custom applications (like https://icomoon.io/, for example). That
> might suit your needs. But, once you create a custom version of their
> fonts it's still a file that you can't break up. Still, a custom
> version of icomoon can be very small and streamlined and would likely
> fit the scenario you describe.
>
> Another alternative would be to not host the font yourself but use
> cloud-based fonts that are more likely to be cached by your users.
> It's not a solution per se but would increase the chances somewhat
> that your users wouldn't have to download the fonts specifically for
> your site.
>
> Blockquote

there is also a way to download the svg file to a js file and then importing it , but it is also complicated so i think the fastest way would be to use the websites that are mentioned at the beginning

Comment: My site score now is `99` :) : https://i.imgur.com/DdyZ30H.png

Comment: Thanks, you too !

Comment: what is a site score ?

Comment: You didn't know that ? Score rating your site performance 

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bunlongheng.com%2F&tab=desktop

Comment: I'm trying to get 100 on both mobile, and desktop, but it almost impossible (especially on mobile).

Comment: i didn't yet managed to do a hosting yet :(  in two weeks i will host my first web app , with Angular

Comment: Well, when you do, make sure your score is good ;)